# Test whether a command option is supported

Tags: bash, shell

In my `.bashrc`, I want to alias grep to `grep --color` *if* the `--color` option is supported. But `--color` isn't supported on old systems like msysgit:

```
$ grep --color
grep: unrecognized option '--color'
$ grep --version
grep (GNU grep) 2.4.2
```

In .bashrc, how can I determine whether an option is supported? I can test for a hard-coded version number, but that will break for versions >2.5:

```
if [[ `grep --version` == *2.5* ]] ; then
    alias grep='grep --color=auto'
fi
```

Is there a more reliable way to test if a command supports an option?

Comment: `grep (GNU grep) 2.4.2 Copyright 2000 Free Software Foundation, Inc.`  Vintage!

Comment: The MSys devs are keen to update the packages they ship, but alas it's harder than you might expect  https://github.com/msysgit/msysgit/issues/31

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Take a grep command which you know will succeed and add the color option E.g.

```
grep --color "a" <<< "a"
```

the return code will be 0 if the option exists, and positive otherwise.

So your bashrc will look like:

```
if grep --color "a" <<<"a" &>/dev/null; then
    alias grep='grep --color=auto'
fi
```

`&>` sends stdout *and* stderr to /dev/null, so if the command fails, it is silenced. But it still returns an error code, which prevents the alias from being set.

Comment: There's no need to wrap the command in the `[[...]]` construct; `if grep --color "a" <<< "a"; then ...; fi` will work as well

Answer (score 0):

```
`
echo s > dummy ;
grep --color s dummy ;
if [[ $? == 2 ]]; then
    echo not supported
fi
`
```